# Unresolved references label within caption for STATA tables

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, labels, stata

I am using stata to generate a table. This STATA generated tex table has label defined within \caption{} command. This labeling should work. But it gives me unresolved references (Table ??). When I manually take out the label which is inside the caption command and post it after \caption{}, the labeling works.

I am struggling to find the problem here. Is there any other way to give command in  STATA that will keep \label{} after \caption{}. Or Can I keep using the same format with some modification?

```
{
  \begingroup
  \let\oldcaption\caption
  \renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\oldcaption{Regression table}}
  \renewcommand\normalsize{\small}%
  \normalsize
  \begin{center}
   \input{../RESULTS/table.tex}        
  \end{center}
 \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by posting a minimal compilable code example (MWE). Also, what is your question (which modifications would you want to do, what is your aim)?

Comment: I want the label to work. No particular modifications just the labeling to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have some auto-generated LaTeX code which uses `\caption{...\label{...}...}` and you would like to change the caption text while preserving the label. This MWE would show the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\oldcaption{Regression table}}

% This table represents the auto-generated code
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{A table\label{A}}
\end{table}

\ref{A} % does not work since the caption text and label was replaced
\end{document}
```

One possible solution would be using the helper macro `\caption@getlabel` offered by the `caption` package which tries to extract the `\label` from it's argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption3}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
  \oldcaption{Regression table}%
  \caption@getlabel#1\label{}\@nil
  \caption@thelabel
}
\makeatother

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{A table\label{A}}
\end{table}

\ref{A}
\end{document}
```

Note that only `caption3` is loaded (and not `caption`) since this package only provides helper macros and no re-definition of existing ones, so it should be compatible with all document classes. (If you load the `caption` package anyway you could drop `\usepackage{caption3}`.)

Caveat: `\caption@getlabel` is an internal macro, not documented in the user documentation of the `caption` package. But I (as author and maintainer of the `caption` package bundle) do not intend to change its interface in the future.